# Positivity and symmetrization

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a symmetric positive matrix, and let $B$ be invertible. Is

$$BAB^{-1} + B^{-1}AB$$

always positive?

---

Let $C$ be a real matrix with real positive spectrum. Is

$$C + C^T$$

positive?

---

Are these two problems the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*EDIT:*  I changed the counterexample to ensure that $B$ is also *symmetric*

**First question**: NO, not even if $B$ is also (symmetric) positive definite

Take

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix}
5 & 2\\\\
2 & 4\end{pmatrix}\qquad
B = \begin{pmatrix}
13 & 15\\\\
15 & 18\end{pmatrix}
$$

Here, both $A$ and $B$ are (symmetric) positive definite, but the sum
$$BAB^{-1} + B^{-1}AB = \begin{pmatrix}
93.3 & 17.9\\\\
17.9 & -75.3\end{pmatrix},
$$
which is not positive.

---

**Added** You might want to generalize the following weaker statement: If $A$ and $B$ are Hermitian, $A$ is positive, and $AB+BA$ is positive, then the matrix $B$ is also positive definite.

Comment: Thanks, that will do. Interesting that the inverse implication holds.

Answer (score 1):

**2nd question**: obviously NO. Just take
$$C=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\\\ a & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
whose spectrum is $(1)$. If $|a|>2$, then $C+C^T$ is not positive.

The questions are not the same, because on the one hand, $(BAB^{-1})^T$ is not equal, in general, to $B^{-1}AB$.

Comment: Yep, that's a good and fast answer, but would you have any claim to do about the first question which is the one I'm really interested into?